# Basic Automated Test of a Javascript Browser Library

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing

I am using Webpack to build a webapp that is designed for the browser.

After my build process I have two files: `index.html` and `app.bundle.js`

To my dismay I have found that the although the `development` Webpack configuration works the `production` configuration does not because of errors during minification.

I am looking for the most basic way to run a test that does the following:

- Opens the `index.html` file (which contains `<script defer="defer" src="app.bundle.js">` and sees if there are any errors when the script contained in `app.bundle.js` runs

That is it.

I need a full Browser environment (`requestianimationframe`, `fetch`, etc.)

I have tried `JSDOM` and I get `Error: Uncaught [ReferenceError: fetch is not defined]` which looks like it has a bunch of issues, and then there are a tremendous amount of overlapping libraries and tools like Phantom.js Zombie.js Pupeteer, headless-chrome etc. and I honestly can't figure out how to just open my app. I have tried to explore all of these tools but they are all complicated.

Ideally I wouldn't have to create a local webserver, but I'd be fine with that if this is what is required.

Answer (score 0):

The 'best' way to do this IMHO, would be to have a full test environment that mirrors your production environment that you can deploy to and then run tests against, using a framework like WebdriverIO or Playwright. But that can be prohibitively expensive and requires a fair amount of devops work.

Your second best option is probably to configure a local webserver on whatever machine you run your tests on and spin up Selenium or Puppeteer tests there. Leveraging a framework like WebdriverIO or Playwright a basic sanity check test shouldn't take more than an hour or two to set up.